boldface \Delta in EB Garamond
I am trying to produce a boldface \Delta symbol. When using the normal font Computer Modern, I can simply use \mathbf{\Delta} which produced the right output. But in a document, I have to use the EB Garamond font. In this setup, the command \mathbf{\Delta} just outputs a normal \Delta. What can I do to remedy this situation?
Many thanks in advance for your help !
I suppose the EB Garamond font doesn't support boldface greek symbols. However, I am convinced there must be a way around that.
